# How can I resolve the UnresolvedAddressException when using a proxy with WebClient on my corporate network?

Tags: spring, spring-webclient

org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: nested exception is java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException] with root cause

I am getting the above error when trying to utilize WebClient on my corporate network which utilizes a proxy

@Bean
public WebClient restClient(){

```
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create()
                    .proxy(proxy -> proxy.type(ProxyProvider.Proxy.HTTP)
                            .address(InetSocketAddress.createUnresolved("http://mycorporate.proxy.com", 8080)));

    ReactorClientHttpConnector connector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);

    return WebClient
            .builder()
            .clientConnector(connector)
            .build();
}
```